# Trying to display file name of selected image in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a part in the site I'm working on where a user can upload an image. I'm using a ModelForm to upload the image, but I have to modify the form itself in order to add the styling from the CSS framework I'm using (Bulma). When I display the form from the template as `{{ pic_form.as_p }}`, it actually has the behavior I want: it shows an upload file button and when you've selected the file (before hitting the submit button) it shows the name of that file so the user can see that the picture has actually been selected.

I've tried looking this problem up online several times with no luck, and I've tried looking at the inspector in the browser to see the html code that is generated by Django using the `{{ pic_form.as_p }}` option, but that looks to be the same as doing it this way.

This is the template code I have for this form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="field">
        {{ pic_form.non_field_errors }}
        <label class="label" for="{{ pic_form.image.id_for_label }}">Upload an image</label>
        <div class="file has-name is-small">
            {{ pic_form.image.errors }}
            <label class="file-label">
                {{ pic_form.image }}
                <span class="file-cta">
                    <span class="file-icon">
                        {% fa5_icon 'upload' 'fas' %}
                    </span>
                    <span class="file-label">
                        Choose a file…
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="file-name">
                    {{ pic_form.image.name }}
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        {{ pic_form.description.errors }}
        <label class="label" for="{{ pic_form.description.id_for_label }}">Description</label>
        {{ pic_form.description }}
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <button class="button is-small is-outlined is-primary is-light" type="submit">Add picture</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need the file name to go in the span section with the file-name class, but I can't figure out how to get that name. The code that's in there right now just gives me "image", which makes sense, since that's the literal name of the field.

If anyone has any idea how I can display the file name before it has been actually saved to the database that would be great, I'm really at a loss. Thanks for reading.

Edit:
I realized this might be useful too, the form model I'm using.

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'file-input'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'})
        }
```

This is what mine currently looks like:
[the version created by the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNm2X.png)

And this is what `{{ form.as_p }}` does, which I would like to replicate, just with the styling from Bulma:
[the version created by django when using their form shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS1O1.png)

Comment: What does it print for now? ``{{ image.name }}``

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I messed up, `{{ image.name }}` displays nothing, I was thinking of `{{ form.image.name }}`, which prints "image" next to the "Choose file..." button

Comment: What do you mean by **filename**? Please explain a bit.

Comment: As in the name of the file in the path. The image I was using to test was "golden-bear-1.jpg", so that was what would show up when I chose a file, and before I hit the add picture button, and what I would like to display to indicate that the file has been selected

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the following to your `Picture` model:

```
import os
....    
    def image_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name)
```

Comment: I don't understand how I would get the name from there in the template without first saving the image to the database

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you wanted to show the name before saving it to the database... not sure that's possible

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to figure it out, but Django is doing it when I display the form using `{{ form.as_p }}` instead of all of the manual stuff with the div formatting to make it look like the rest of my site